# Ввод / вывод c#

Tags: c#

Господа, есть примитивный код, который считывает введенную строку, потом считанную строку преобразует в массив символов и далее выводит в цикле каждый символ отдельно:

```
static void Main()
    {
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(Console.ReadLine());
        char[] ch = new char[sr.ReadToEnd().Length];
        sr.Read(ch, 0, ch.Length);
        for (int x = 0; x < ch.Length; x++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ch[x]); 
        }
    }
```

Однако возникает проблема в этом месте кода `char[] ch = new char[sr.ReadToEnd().Length];`. Так как здесь создается массив длиной в количестве символов введенной строки. И следовательно при считывании всех символов получается, что позиция указателя становиться в конец строки, и далее он из-за этого на экран выводит пустые символы.

Господа, подскажите, пожалуйста, как именно в этом случае установить позицию на 0 или другой путь динамического получения количества символов. Спасибо.

Comment: скажите, а в чем смысл сначала считывать всю строку, чтобы узнать ее длину,
 
    sr.ReadToEnd().Length

 а потом еще раз считывать эту же строку уже другим методом sr.Read? Разве не достаточно первого считывания чтобы получить корректное значение строки? Заодно и проблемы со сместившимся указателем не будет

Comment: 1. А как иначе узнать размер массива символов, если я не знаю, что будет введено?
2. Я просто хотел поэксперементировать с массивом. А именно метод Read() и выводит символы из массива. 

Или я чушь говорю? Запарился я че-то.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и терпение. Суть программы тут такова, что мне нужно поместить введенную строку в массив символов. Для этого мне нужно знать размер создаваемого массива. Потому я использую char[] ch = new char[sr.ReadToEnd().Length];. Вторым шагом sr.Read(ch, 0, ch.Length); я вношу введенные символы в массив. Ну и третьим шагом в цикле я пытаюсь их вывести. Поэтому я использую чтение дважды.

Comment: >Вторым шагом sr.Read(ch, 0, ch.Length); я вношу введенные символы в массив

хм..еще раз - зачем вам нужна вторая (возможно, очень дорогая по времени) операция чтения? У вас есть **уже готовая строка**

Comment: Да, я с вами полностью согласен. Но тогда я не могу понять, зачем вообще нужен метод Read(char [], offset, count). ??

Comment: тот факт, что он не нужен для решения конкретно вашего примера, не означает, что он не нужен вообще. Бывают ситуации, когда информацию нужно читать отдельными порциями с заранее известными размерами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@DreamChild](/users/10162/dreamchild)](/users/10162/dreamchild) правильно говорит, что не нужно читать строку два раза.
Нужно просто считать всё в строку (она же массив символов), у которой есть и длина, и доступ посимвольный.

```
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(Console.ReadLine());
        string myStr = sr.ReadToEnd();

        /* идём посимвольно */
        foreach (var ch in myStr)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ch);
        }

        /* можно так  */
        for (int i = 0; i < myStr.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(myStr[i]);
        }
```

Comment: А зачем так сложно? Может быть, просто 

    string myStr = Console.ReadLine();